# Dojo grid refresh and scroll position

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have a Grid in Dojo,

```
var myGrid = new (declare([Grid, DijitRegistry]))({
    store: myStore, // this is a Observable(Memory())
    columns:[
        {field: "field1", label: "A", sortable: false},
        {field: "field2", label: "B", sortable: false},
        {field: "field3", label: "C", sortable: false},
        {field: "field4", label: "D", sortable: false},
        {field: "field5", label: "E", sortable: false}
    ],
    selectionMode: "single",
    cellNavigation: true,
    queryOptions: {
        sort:[{attribute: "field1", descending: true}]
    }
},
    myDomRef
);
```

At times I need to refresh the grid

```
myGrid.refresh();
```

This grid has a scrollbar at the right and I would like to retain the position of the scrollbar. But when I do a refresh, it scrolls back to the top.

How could I retain the scroll position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `OnDemandGrid`, it supports a `keepScrollPosition` property, which you can either define on the grid instance to influence all `refresh` calls, or pass specifically when calling `refresh` (e.g. `grid.refresh({ keepScrollPosition: true })`).

Comment: Thank you so much, where did you find this? I've been looking and couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: It's listed in https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.4.0/doc/components/core-components/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid.md#property-summary (though admittedly that's apparently out of alphabetical order at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

Try grabbing the `<div>` object containing the grid and get the current scroll position:

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var x = elmnt.scrollLeft;
var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
```

Save the position and then refresh the grid.  After the refresh completes, restore the scroll positions:

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
elmnt.scrollLeft = x;
elmnt.scrollTop = y;
```

I think the scroll values will be on the `<div>` object in this case.  If not, use `inspect element` in your web browser while holding the mouse pointer over the scroll bar you want.  This should allow you to find the element that needs to have it's scroll saved and restored.

If the entire pages is refreshed in a CGI type environment, you could pass these values as URL parms to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, `keepScrollPosition` is the solution in case you are using `OnDemandGrid`.

In case you are using `dgrid/Grid`, `keepScrollPosition` is not supported.

This is how I solved the problem with the jumping scrollbars (this applies for both horizontal and vertical scrollbars):
`Grid` has a method `getScrollPosition()`. By calling this method right before `refresh()`, you can save the positions of both scrollbars and jump back to them after refresh is done. Code should look something like this:

```
var scrollpos = myGrid.getScrollPosition();
myGrid.refresh();
myGrid.scrollTo(scrollpos);
```

One limitation in this solution is by old IE browsers, there is a noticeable back and forth jump.